# USB Flash drive unmount

Tags: android

I am writing an application that needs to detect when a Flash drive - which I'm connected via OTG cable - mounted/unmounted. I figured out what action is indicating to BradcastReceiver when flash drive is connecting. When I tap to "Select to remove USB mass storage safely" system write to me "USB mass storage removed safely". But I don't know what action is fireing.
I've tried

```
android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED
android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED
android.intent.action.UMS_DISCONNECTED
```

actions but doesn't work either of them.